# Remove all characters except regex pattern in array

Tags: regex, powershell

So Im creating an array of all the versions of a particular pkg in a directory
What I want to do is strip out all the characters except the version numbers
The first array has info such as

GoogleChrome.45.45.34.nupkg
GoogleChrome.34.28.34.nupkg

So the output I need is
45.45.34
34.28.34

```
$dirList = Get-ChildItem $sourceDir -Recurse -Include "*.nupkg" -Exclude 
$pkgExclude | 
   Foreach-Object {$_.Name}

$reg = '.*[0-9]*.nupkg'
$appName ='GoogleChrome'

$ouText = $dirList | Select-String $appName$reg -AllMatches | % { 
$_.Matches.Value }
$ouText
$verReg='(\d+)(.)(?!nupkg)'
```

The last regex matches the pattern of what I want to keep but I cant figure out how to extract what I dont need.

Comment: Try `Select-String '(?<=GoogleChrome\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)+' -AllMatches`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to post-process matches if you apply the right pattern from the start.

In order to extract `.` separated digits in between `GoogleChrome.` and `.nupkg` you may use

```
Select-String '(?<=GoogleChrome\.)[\d.]+(?=\.nupkg)' -AllMatches
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3DGoogleChrome%5C.%29%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5C.nupkg%29&i=GoogleChrome.45.45.34.nupkg%0D%0AGoogleChrome.34.28.34.nupkg)

**Details**

- `(?<=GoogleChrome\.)` - the location should be preceded with `GoogleChrome.` substring
- `[\d.]+` - one or more digits or/and `.`
- `(?=\.nupkg)` - there must be `.nupkg` immediately to the right of the current location.

If `.nupkg` should not be relied upon, use

```
Select-String '(?<=GoogleChrome\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)+' -AllMatches
```

Here, `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` will match 1 or more digits followed with 1 or more occurrences of a `.` and 1+ digits only if preceded with `GoogleChrome.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d+.?)+(?!nupkg)
```

this would give you desired output in the match, check the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xIIGv1/1)